# Mixing string and template variable in django

Tags: html, django

I have an html site consisting of many "cards", each card being a template and each card containing a list with an id tag.

Since the form IDs have to be unique I can not just name them with a hardcoded string but have to incorporate some card specific identifier.

I tried the following

```
    <ul id= "tags"{{ object.id }}>
        <li>Tag2</li>
    </ul>
```

which I then try to refer to in a java script using

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#tags"{{ object.title }}).tagit({
           ...
        });
    });
</script>
```

But unfortunately this does not seam to work.
Does anybody know how to mix strings and template variables in such a situation correctly?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? have you tired just id="tags{{ object.id }}"?

Comment: you need: <ul id="tags{{ object.id }}">. Now you are getting <ul id="tags"1> in the output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to place the template code inside the quotation marks.

```
<ul id="tags{{ object.id }}">
    <li>Tag2</li>
</ul>
```